# How can I cast as a user object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, casting, active-directory

I've got the following code which connects to every computer on the domain and checks the members of the local administrators group:

```
Foreach ($Computer in Get-ADComputer -Filter *){
    $Path = $Computer.Path
    $Name = ([ADSI]"$Path").Name
    Write-Host $Name
    $members = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Name/Administrators"
    $members = @($members.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
    ForEach($member in $members){
        Write-Host $member.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $member, $null)
        Write-Host $member.GetType().InvokeMember("AdsPath", 'GetProperty', $null, $member, $null)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to store the value of $member in a $User object of some sort, so I can actually reference the attributes without all the crazy invoker stuff.

E.g., in pseudocode I want:

```
$user = (User) $member;
Write-Host $user.Name
Write-Host $user.AdsPath
```

I'm new to PowerShell, however... and I'm not sure if I really understand how to cast to an object type within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a custom object (or `PSObject`) with the specified members and values:

```powershell
Foreach ($Computer in Get-ADComputer -Filter *){
    $Path=$Computer.Path
    $Name=([ADSI]"$Path").Name
    write-host $Name
    $members =[ADSI]"WinNT://$Name/Administrators"
    $members = @($members.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
    ForEach($member in $members){
        $propsWanted = @('Name' , 'AdsPath') # An array of the properties you want
        $properties = @{} # This is an empty hashtable, or associative array, to hold the values
        foreach($prop in $propsWanted) {
            $properties[$prop] = $member.GetType().InvokeMember($prop, 'GetProperty', $null, $member, $null)
        }
        $user = New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
        $user # This is an object representing the user
    }
}
```

Just to go over some of the changes:

1. I'm putting all of the property names you want into an array `$propsWanted`, and then iterating over that to invoke and get each one. This lets you easily work with more properties later, by adding the property names in a single place.
2. The `$properties` hashtable will store a key/value pair, where the key is the property name, and the value is the property value.
3. Once the hashtable is filled, you can pass it to the `-Property` parameter of `New-Object` when creating a `PSObject`.

You should use your new object and have a look at by testing a few things:

- Pipe it to the `Format-` cmdlets to see various views:

  ```powershell
  $user | Format-Table
  $user | Format-List
  ```
- Check the values of its properties directly:

  ```powershell
  $user.Name
  $user.AdsPath
  ```
- If you make an array of these objects, you can filter them for example:

  ```powershell
  $user | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*Admin' }
  ```

## Alternatives

You might try using CIM or WMI, which will actually be a little friendlier:

#### CIM

```powershell
$group = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Group  -Filter "Name = 'Administrators'"

Get-CimAssociatedInstance -InputObject $group -ResultClassName Win32_UserAccount |

select -ExpandProperty Caption

Get-CimAssociatedInstance -InputObject $group -ResultClassName Win32_Group |

select -ExpandProperty Caption
```

#### WMI

```powershell
$query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Group.Domain='$($env:COMPUTERNAME)',Name='Administrators'} WHERE ResultClass = Win32_UserAccount"

Get-WmiObject -Query $query | Select -ExpandProperty Caption

$query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Group.Domain='$($env:COMPUTERNAME)',Name='Administrators'} WHERE ResultClass = Win32_Group"

Get-WmiObject -Query $query | Select -ExpandProperty Caption
```

#### .NET 3.5 Required for this method:

```powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

$ctype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine

$context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ctype, $env:COMPUTERNAME

$idtype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName

$group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, 'Administrators')

$group.Members |

select @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName
```

### Attribution

All of the above alternatives were taken directly from this "Hey, Scripting Guy!" article, [The Admin's First Steps: Local Group Membership](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/10/27/the-admin-s-first-steps-local-group-membership.aspx). It goes into detail about all of these, including the `[ADSI]` method. Worth a read.

## How to Actually Cast

I just realized I didn't actually answer this question, even though it's not exactly what you needed. Classes/types are specified with square brackets. In fact, when you did this:

```powershell
[ADSI]"WinNT://$Name/Administrators"
```

You casted a `[String]` (the string literal in `"`) to an `[ADSI]` object, which worked because `[ADSI]` knows what to do with it.

Other examples:

```powershell
[int]"5"
[System.Net.IPAddress]'8.8.8.8'
```

Since we don't know the type of the "user" object you're seeking (or it's not even really loaded), you can't use this method.

Comment: Wow, this will definitely work, but is there really no standard "User Object" which something can be cast to in order to by default have all the properties?

Comment: Well essentially you're using a COM object here, and that makes all this a little strange. There might be such a thing, but it appears to be hidden, or I'm not aware of how to get at it when using the `[ASDI]` object.

Comment: I've added some alternatives for you, a link that explains them in greater detail. You should definitely check out the link.

Comment: Also just realized that I never told you how casting actually works, so that's in there now too.